# I need to set up the cron job, but I don't know my magento file system owner username

Tags: cron, crontab

I am stucked in crontab -u  -e
because I don't know file user name? 
How to find it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the user logged in console... just type

```
id
```

That would return current user, who I suppose will run `bin/magento` commands

About filesystem owner, go to Magento root & type

```
ls -la
```

So you can see which user & group are the owner for files & folders, something like this

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 raulsanchez www-data       4096 Apr 18 10:04 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 raulsanchez raulsanchez    4096 Apr  5 13:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 raulsanchez www-data       4096 Apr  5 13:58 app
-rw-rw-r--  1 raulsanchez raulsanchez     138 Apr  5 13:58 auth.json.sample
drwxr-xr-x  2 raulsanchez www-data       4096 Apr  5 13:58 bin
-rw-rw-r--  1 raulsanchez raulsanchez  566648 Apr  5 13:58 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 raulsanchez raulsanchez    1978 Apr  5 13:58 composer.json
...
drwxrwsrwx 11 raulsanchez www-data       4096 Jun 13 15:11 var
drwxrwsr-x 40 raulsanchez www-data       4096 Apr  5 13:58 vendor
```

Comment: Thanks bro, # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 14 www  www       4096 Aug  4 18:39 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root      4096 Aug  4 15:03 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www  www        479 Aug  4 17:49 404.html

Comment: when I type crontab -u www -e in the root of mangento file,  shows "no crontab for www - using an empty one"
when I type crontab -u root -e  it show "6 0 * * * "/root/.acme.sh"/acme.sh --cron --home "/root/.acme.sh" > /dev/null
30 1 * * *  /www/server/cron/f45cdc9fe92525f4a35c51df236f25a4 >> /www/server/cron/f45cdc9fe92525f4a35c51df236f25a4.log 2>&1
"  what shoud I do?

Comment: I was hoping to not see "root" as your response... :( You should create a new user, or request that to your hosting provider, as running console commands with "root" could lead to heavy problems, and at same time "root" should never be the webserver user in a regular installation

Comment: Thanks for your advice, bro, I fear that if i compile the user name, all my site would cracked...